# Regex replace a link in php

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am not good at with regular expressions, I need some help.

I have a link link this below:

> http://www.mydomain.com/1/1/5/1/some-name-123-115194_7_9.jpg

What should be the regex to get with php like below:

> http://www.mydomain.com/1/1/5/1/115194_7_9.jpg

This is what I have tried so far:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)(\w+)/', $str,$matches);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: What have you tried? Here, [use this online regex tester I just found by googling](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: I have tried this. preg_match_all('/(\d+)(\w+)/', $str,$matches);

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a regex.  I'd use the `parse_url()` function to break apart the URL into its component parts, then change the filename at the end, then reconstruct the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`:

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/1/1/5/1/some-name-123-115194_7_9.jpg";

echo preg_replace('#(.+/).+-(.+)#','$1$2',$url)

>>> http://www.mydomain.com/1/1/5/1/115194_7_9.jpg
```

Rexplanation:

```
(.+/)   # Match everything upto the last / and capture
.+-     # Match upto the last -
(.+)    # Match and capture everything else 
        # Replace with 
$1$2    # The first and second capture groups
```